# Windows 2003 Standard IIS Remote Admin - Can't login

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

I have just installed Windows Server 2003 Standard Edition and therefore IIS6 (comes as standard). I have also install the windows component that enable the administration of IIS from the browser (https://server:8098/). The problem I have is that I have to log-in to this tool but the Server Administrator u/name and p/word does not let me in.

The Windows documentation on this tool (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324282) says "You are prompted for a user name and password that exist on the Web Server" but none of the standard user acounts on the server let me in.

Thanks,

Comment: I have RDP setup and can connect that way to administer IIS but would prefer to use the Browser based admin tool, which is the one I am having the problem with. Any suggestions>? Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple ideas:

- Take a look at the security log on the server for clues.
- Look at the "Directory Security" tab on the properties of the admin site and ensure "Enable anonymous access" is unchecked.  You will need to use "Integrated Windows authentication" or "Basic authentication".  If you use Basic auth then the password is sent across then network base64 encoded - you will want to use SSL to encrypt it.
- Is there a specific requirement to use the web tools?  You can download [Internet Information Services (IIS) 6.0 Manager for Windows XP](http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?familyid=F9C1FB79-C903-4842-9F6C-9DB93643FDB7&displaylang=en) from Microsoft and run it from a client.

Comment: Sorted, "Integrated Windows Authentication" was not select as default and the Microsoft guide did not say to enable it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure now, haven't set up a Win 2003 box in a while but as far as I remember you have to activate remote desktop first and then you can use a RDP client to access the server.  I recommend that over the ActiveX RDP client.

Comment: have RDP setup and can connect that way to administer IIS but would prefer to use the Browser based admin tool, which is the one I am having the problem with. Any suggestions>? Thanks for your responses

Answer (score 0):

Is the server part of a domain?  It may be defaulting to a domain username/password combo rather than a local username/password.

Try "server.domain.local\administrator" or "administrator@server.domain.local".

Comment: a helpful step in the right direction but still no joy. Have just removed security on that site and it's fine so is certainly a strange one.

Comment: It's caught me out a few times, you think you're loggin in as a local user and it's authenticating you against AD, or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the permissions on that site in IIS - make sure you are using an account that is a member of a group specifically assigned permissions. I understand that the builtin admin account is not working but its possible the site permissions have changed removing that account or group. - hope that makes some sort of sense

Answer (score 0):

This might be unlikely, but are you trying to use a username that has a blank password? Windows restricts remote access when using those accounts.

If that's the case, you can check the Group Policy (`gpedit.msc` for local computer, or the one for domains if it's in a domain.):

```
Computer Configuration
 Windows Settings
  Security Settings
   Local Policies
    Accounts: Limit local account use of blank passwords to console logon only
```